# 404 error when rendering template with image

Tags: javascript, python, html, image, templates

Folders are as follows:
**Project**

static folder--index.html

templates folder--newyork.html + image folder--newyork.jpg

webapp.py

When I run my code through commander everything works other than the images. For some reason the images wont display and it comes up with a 404 error in the Cmder prompt. Here is my template i'm using:

```
<!doctype html>
<title>New York</title>
<h1>New York</h1>       
<p>
New York is a state in the northeastern United States, and is the 27th-most extensive, fourth-most populous, and seventh-most densely populated U.S. state. New York is bordered by New Jersey and Pennsylvania to the south and Connecticut, Massachusetts, and Vermont to the east. The state has a maritime border in the Atlantic Ocean with Rhode Island, east of Long Island, as well as an international border with the Canadian provinces of Quebec to the north and Ontario to the west and north. 
</p>
<img src="images/newyork1.jpg" alt="New York" style="width:750px;height:350px;">
<p>
The state of New York, with an estimated 19.8 million residents in 2015, is often referred to as New York State to distinguish it from New York City, the state's most populous city and its economic hub.
</p>
```

Here is my index.html I'm using:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
  $("#newyorkbutton").click(function(){
    $.get("/newyork", function(data, status){
      $("#city").html(data);
    });
  });
});
</script>
</head>
<body>
<h2>Welcome to My Travels</h2> 
<input type="submit" name="NewYork" id="newyorkbutton" value="New York">
<h2>Welcome to My Travels</h2> 
<div id = "city">
<p>
Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum
</p>

</div>
</body> 
</html>
```

And Finally my python code I'm running:

```
from flask import Flask, render_template, request

app = Flask(__name__)  


@app.route("/")
def root():
    return app.send_static_file('index.html')

@app.route("/newyork") 
def newyork(): 
   return render_template('newyork.html')

if __name__ == "__main__":     
    app.run()
```

Comment: So where is the code to serve the images?

Answer (score 0):

There are a couple of options for dealing with this in Flask.

Simplest option: you can move the `images` folder into your `static` directory and change the `src` attribute of your from `images/newyork1.jpg` tag to `url_for('static', filename='images/newyork1.jpg)`.

Or you can define a route for your `images` directory in your `webapp.py` file with a `<path:path>` appended as catch-all. Then define a function with a `path` parameter that returns a call to `send_from_directory` with the arguments `images` and `path`. Make sure you import `send_from_directory` from Flask at the top of your file.

```
@app.route('/images/<path:path>')
def images(path):
    return send_from_directory('images', path)
```